# reducing array of objects to sum up for multiple properties

Tags: javascript

I am having array of objects where i want to reduce the array and get the count of two properties. When my array length is more than one it works but when its one or less it doesn't

```
const data = [{id: 1, count:3 , alt_count: 2}, {id: 2, count:4 , alt_count: 5}];
const countObj = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      return {
        count_total: acc.count + curr.count,
        alt_count_total: acc.alt_count + curr.alt_count,
      };
    });
 console.log(countObj) // giving me both count_total and alt_count_total
```

But here its not giving me, instead it gives me the same object

```
const data = [{id: 1, count:3 , alt_count: 2}];
const countObj = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
          return {
            count_total: acc.count + curr.count,
            alt_count_total: acc.alt_count + curr.alt_count,
          };
        });
console.log(countObj) // giving me entire first object
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#initialvalue) to `reduce`.

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  count: 3,
  alt_count: 2
}];

const countObj = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    count: acc.count + curr.count,
    alt_count: acc.alt_count + curr.alt_count,
  };
}, {
  count: 0,
  alt_count: 0
});

console.log(countObj);
```